# Как перенести таблицу в удобный для публикации формат?

Tags: r, markdown

Что делать если нужно не просто получить результат, но и презентовать его?

Я знаю про rmarkdown, но как оформить именно таблицу?
Поделитесь, кто как с этим справляется.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для таблицы самый очевидный вариант - `kable()`.

По другим вариантам из ответа выше:
**xtable** и **pander** имеют методы для печати различных *объектов*, например, возвращаемых функциями `lm()`, `t.test` и многими другими. Это очень удобно и полезно, и `kable()` тут не справится. LaTeX изучать не обязательно, вывод в html также работает.

**xtable** с R Markdown используется следующим образом:

```
print(xtable(fit1), type = "html")
```

При этом нужно не забыть указать в чанке ```` ```{r, results='asis'} ````

**pander** еще проще: `pander(fit1)`.

Есть еще относительно экзотический способ, полезный при создании инфографики или при подготовке материалов для печати в солидном журнале: https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob

Позволяет получать таблицы в виде красивых картинок, а также комбинировать их с графиками, например

[image: gridExtra]

[image: gridExtra]

Answer (score 3):

Для оформления таблиц есть много пакетов. Эти пакеты позволяют генерировать код в форматах LaTeX, pandoc, HTML. Более менее систематизированный обзор можно посмотреть на CRAN Task Views в разделе [Reproducible Research](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html). Ниже приведу краткий список пакетов, которые предоставляют функции для работы с таблицами.

- [knitr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) (функция `kable()`)
- [htmlTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/index.html)
- [xtable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html)
- [pander](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/index.html)

Я работал с каждым из них и могу подтвердить их работоспособность. Также могут быть полезны пакеты `broom`, `xtable` и `pander`, которые предоставляет функции для оформления типичных объектов R, получаемых в ходе статистического анализа (например, результаты регрессионного или дисперсионного анализа). Посмотреть поддерживаемые пакетом методы можно следующим образом (аналогично для других пакетов):

```
library(pander)
methods(pander)
```

Пример вывода `kable()` в формате `markdown`:

```
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), format = "markdown")

#> |                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|    wt|  qsec| vs| am| gear| carb|
#> |:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|----:|-----:|-----:|--:|--:|----:|----:|
#> |Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620| 16.46|  0|  1|    4|    4|
#> |Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875| 17.02|  0|  1|    4|    4|
#> |Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93| 3.85| 2.320| 18.61|  1|  1|    4|    1|
#> |Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110| 3.08| 3.215| 19.44|  1|  0|    3|    1|
#> |Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175| 3.15| 3.440| 17.02|  0|  0|    3|    2|
#> |Valiant           | 18.1|   6|  225| 105| 2.76| 3.460| 20.22|  1|  0|    3|    1|
```

Comment: Нет ли материалов на русском языке? Latex, к сожалению, я не знаю

Comment: В большинстве случаев достаточно посмотреть примеры из встроенной справки к соответствующим функциям. Более того, `pandoc` позволяет конвертировать множество разнообразных форматов (в том числе и LaTeX).

Comment: есть еще `texreg` и `stargazer`